# Opencv_4 is not building in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, opencv, gradle, opencv3.0

I am facing this issue in updated versions of dart and flutter and freshly added open_cv4 package and also facing issue for sample code given...

Launching lib\image_pick_services.dart on motorola one 5G UW ace in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':opencv_4' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried changing different versions of kotlin, Gradle and aslo dart 2.0 but in vein